# Is it possible for sonarqube to store the rules in git along with the source code of the project?

Tags: sonarqube

Is it possible for sonarqube to store the rules in git along with the source code of the project? 
In other words, is it possible to versioned rules for different branches of the project?

Comment: how about adding dotsettings file in project & providing that file in sonarqube? each project will have different dotsettings with different rules.

Comment: Is your question about a "how to store a quality profile"?

Comment: Some validation rules depend on the functionality of the project. Rules will be modified with the project. I want to add a plugin that will take the rules from git.

Answer (score 2):

**Is it possible to store a profile in Git?**

Yes. You can export a profile to file using the Back up feature. (Note that [rule customizations aren't included](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-5366))

**Is it possible to have *SonarQube* store profiles in Git?**

No. During analysis your SCM will be queried for blame information, but no part of the SonarQube ecosystem performs commits.

**Is it possible to version your profiles and apply different versions to different branches of a project?**

Yes, but why would you want to?

There's no point in re-analyzing branches that aren't changing. Which implies that if you improve/tighten your standards, you don't want to apply those higher standards to the new development that's going on in your branches.

"But new rules would raise all kinds of new issues in our branches & I don't want to have to address them because we're not doing new development there, just fixes." I can hear you saying.

Sure, but if you're using a recent version of SonarQube (>=6.3) then those new issues will be raised with a date that matches the blame date of the line. I.E. they won't be raised as *leak period* issues, but as *old* issues. Since you're presumably keeping the leak period clean on your branches, this should all work out.

But to answer your question, there's really no need to store old profiles in SCM, just [peel off copies in SonarQube](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Quality+Profiles#QualityProfiles-Copytherulesfromoneprofiletoanother?) and assign them to the appropriate branch projects.

But if you insist on doing this via backups checked in to SCM be aware that you'll need to reconstitute (re-import) your profiles into SonarQube prior to analysis. You can't just point an analysis at a file containing a list of rules and expect it to work.

Comment: Yes, but why would you want to?

Some validation rules depend on the functionality of the project. Rules will be modified with the project.
I want to add a plugin that will take the rules from git.